# How can I attach a photo in Gmail on iPhone rather than inline it with the body of the mail?

Tags: iphone, ios, photos, gmail, attachments

I want to attach a photo in [Gmail on iPhone](https://apps.apple.com/us/app/gmail-email-by-google/id422689480).

If I open Gmail and click on the paperclip attachment icon and select a photo, it does not attach a photo  but instead it inserts the photo within the mail.

How can I attach a photo in Gmail rather than inline it with the body of the mail?

Comment: My suspicion is that this isn't possible within Gmail, but it should be easy if you are willing to use another client.

Comment: I've just tried this and noticed that even though the file shows as inline when sending the email, it'll be an attachment when the email in received. I think this is just because of the mobile version